# What are good resources for learning how to manage builds and releases?

Tags: build-process, build-automation, release-management

I recently took on the responsibility for managing our company's builds and releases. We ship our products as both a web service and as a licensed product that customers can install on their internal servers.

My job involves making sure QA has the builds they need for testing, which may come from the main development branch or feature-specific branches, depending on their current focus, and may be for one of two different products. It also means releasing our products internally for dogfooding, which means we deploy to an internal server. Finally, I cut official builds for our customers by creating new versions of the installer for those who install internally, and pushing updates to the website for our hosted customers.

So far, I've picked up the Pragmatic Programmers' [Ship It!](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/prj/ship-it) and [Release It!](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/mnee/release-it), both of which seem useful. What other books I should pick up and read? Are there communities or well-known bloggers I should follow that deal specifically with the challenges of building, deploying and shipping web services to our own servers and to customers internal servers?

Answer (score 2):

I really liked [Pragmatic Project Automation](http://pragprog.com/titles/auto/pragmatic-project-automation)

Answer (score 1):

[CM Crossroads](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/) is an excellent resource.